# Dynamic Pretty URL's in Yii2 using get Parameters

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to generate dynamic URL's using yii2 routing, but I didnt find any proper example for what I am looking for

I have a page which has list of users. If I click on any user name it gets redirected to particular user's profile page.

The URL for profile page is like

```
https://www.example.com/frontend/web/users/profile?id=1&name=xyz
```

I want to show this URL as `https://www.example.com/xyz`   where xyz is users name.

I have seen examples of pretty URL's but couldnt find any specific example.

How to such dynamic URL's. Please help.

Comment: Suppose you could do this, what would happen if two users have the same name?

Comment: @paul I will concatenate id and name fields

Comment: Would you please post the configuration of your web-server?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fully remove static link from link. You can leave profile and remove other. Then your link will be https://www.example.com/profile/xyz
First of all add to config:

```
'urlManager' => [
          'showScriptName' => false,
          'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
          'rules' => [
              'profile/<name>' => 'users/profile',
               ...
          ],
```

Change your action:

```
public function actionProfile($name) {
        $user= User::findOne(['name'=>$name]);
```